# How to change the canvas background color from checkered to white in paint.net?

Tags: paint.net

I am working with a .tif image with transparent background in paint.net

I want to see what the image will look like on a white background. (The transparent sections.

I can kludge it by creating an extra "bottom" layer and filling it with white, but would be nice to do that with a setting.

Comment: It should be possible to edit the transparency settings, but I think it will be quicker to create that extra white layered background, especially if you want to go back to the checkered transparent setting. But it has been years since I last worked with paint.net.

Comment: Could you replace the transparent color with the recolor tool? https://www.getpaint.net/doc/latest/RecolorTool.html

Comment: Same here, Paint.NET is very limited, it lacks from BASIC configurable features.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely not possible.

I went through all settings and looked up online. Many people asked this years ago, and the answer has always been "make the background layer yourself."

Comment: Is there any way, when using the delete key, to let it leave white there instead of transparent?

Answer (score 0):

The checkerboard is the standard and universal view of a transparent area on the screen. File save as jpg will preview the image, and if you press ok save the image without a transparent color, in other words, "white."